# Use .mak files on Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, makefile, streaming

I'm trying to test the live555 libraries (live555.com) on Windows. Here are the instructions: http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/#config-windows

I managed to generate the .mak files, but now I do not know how to use them in Visual Studio 2010 to start any of the applications (as openRTSP or playSIP).

How I can use or open .mak files in Visual Studio 2010?

Thanks for the help.
Greetings!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know you can't open .maks in recent visual studios - you have to compile them from the command-line instead.

Open a Visual Studio command prompt (or run vsvars32.bat from the VS Common\Tools directory in a regular command prompt) then try

```
nmake /f abc.mak
```

I've a feeling you could open makefiles them way back in VS6 but can't remember - it might have been generate them instead.

Answer (score 14):

In trying to compile live555 with Visual Studio 2012 I had similar issues. Here's some stuff I needed to do to make it build. Items 3+ are based on these instructions for [compiling live555 with vs2008](http://tdistler.com/2011/05/14/live555-compiling-with-vs2008)

1) I had to copy nmake.exe *into* the VC\bin directory from another location (it was somewhere else). See [social MSDN page](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/vssetup/thread/4db6024e-cb2c-4992-9fb8-4aeefc194733) for more info.

2) In addition I also had to remove question marks from the .mak files ("prefix? =...", for example) for conditional assignment or it wouldn't build (the error was "too many names to the left of =").

3) Open the ‘win32config’ file and change the TOOLS32=... variable to
    your VS2008 install directory. For me, it’s `TOOLS32=C:\Program Files
    (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC`

4) In ‘win32config’, modify the
    `LINK_OPTS_0=`... line from msvcirt.lib to msvcrt.lib. This fixes the
link error: `LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file
'msvcirt.lib'`

5) Open the Visual Studio command prompt.
From the ‘live’ source directory, run `genWindowsMakefiles`

6) Now you’re ready to build. Simply run the following commands:

```
cd liveMedia
nmake /B -f liveMedia.mak

cd ..\groupsock
nmake /B -f groupsock.mak
cd ..\UsageEnvironment
nmake /B -f UsageEnvironment.mak
cd ..\BasicUsageEnvironment
nmake /B -f BasicUsageEnvironment.mak
cd ..\testProgs
nmake /B -f testProgs.mak
cd ..\mediaServer
nmake /B -f mediaServer.mak
```

Comment: You, sir/madam, are a gentleman/lady and a scholar. Many thanks.

Comment: Very useful. In my VS2012 setup with default install options some of the paths are different: VC lives in Program Files (x86)\VC. I also had to copy win32.mak and ntwin32.mak from \Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A into the live555 tree. Then it worked great!

Answer (score 3):

Download and build script for "Visual Studio 2017 Community", C++ Features required (Setup Dialog of Visual Studio) 7Zip is also required.

**install-live555.cmd**

```
PowerShell (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/public/live555-latest.tar.gz','live555-latest.tar.gz');
"%PROGRAMFILES%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -aoa live555-latest.tar.gz
"%PROGRAMFILES%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -aoa live555-latest.tar

powershell -Command "(gc live\win32config) -replace '!include    <ntwin32.mak>', '#!include    <ntwin32.mak>' | Out-File live\win32config"
powershell -Command "(gc live\win32config) -replace 'c:\\Program Files\\DevStudio\\Vc', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503' | Out-File live\win32config"
powershell -Command "(gc live\win32config) -replace '\(TOOLS32\)\\bin\\cl', '(TOOLS32)\bin\HostX86\x64\cl' | Out-File live\win32config"
powershell -Command "(gc live\win32config) -replace 'LINK =         \$\(link\) -out:', 'LINK = link ws2_32.lib /out:' | Out-File live\win32config"
powershell -Command "(gc live\win32config) -replace 'LIBRARY_LINK =     lib -out:', 'LIBRARY_LINK = lib /out:' | Out-File live\win32config"
powershell -Command "(gc live\win32config) -replace 'msvcirt.lib', 'msvcrt.lib' | Out-File live\win32config"

call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools\vsdevcmd" -arch=x64

cd live

call genWindowsMakefiles

cd liveMedia
del *.obj *.lib
nmake /B -f liveMedia.mak
cd ..\groupsock
del *.obj *.lib
nmake /B -f groupsock.mak
cd ..\UsageEnvironment
del *.obj *.lib
nmake /B -f UsageEnvironment.mak
cd ..\BasicUsageEnvironment
del *.obj *.lib
nmake /B -f BasicUsageEnvironment.mak
cd ..\testProgs
del *.obj *.lib
nmake /B -f testProgs.mak
cd ..\mediaServer
del *.obj *.lib
nmake /B -f mediaServer.mak
cd ..

pause
```